# Generate a shadow jar by feature, with Gradle in a Java project

Tags: gradle

I try to use the java plugin feature (https://docs.gradle.org/5.3-rc-1/userguide/feature_variants.html) to declare 2 versions of the same dependency, and generate at the end, 2 jars:

```
java {
    registerFeature('v1') {
        usingSourceSet(sourceSets.main)
    }

    registerFeature('v2') {
        usingSourceSet(sourceSets.main)
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly project(':djobi-core')

    v1Implementation(group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark-13_' + scalaVersion, version:'6.2.2') {
        exclude group: "org.scala-lang"
    }

    v2Implementation(group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch-spark-13_' + scalaVersion, version:'6.3.2') {
        exclude group: "org.scala-lang"
    }
}

ShadowJar {

}
```

But it generates only 1, is it a good way to use `feature` feature like this?

Comment: Where does the shadowJar come from? Are you using the `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow` plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default task `shadowJar` uses the `runtime` configuration, see the [docs](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/dependencies/)-

In order to shadow configurations `v1` and `v2` we can define two new tasks, of type `ShadowJar` (they need to be configured).

Actually, `v1` and `v2` could be defined as "normal" configurations, that is, avoiding to use the feature-variants (it is simpler; moreover when trying to use shadowJar and the `v1Implementation` above, we have an error (`Resolving configuration 'v1Implementation' directly is not allowed`).

See the edited example below; it can be built with `gradle shadowJar1 shadowJar2`.

---

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:5.0.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
  }
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
  v1 {
    extendsFrom(implementation)
  }
  v2 {
    extendsFrom(implementation)
  }
}

dependencies {
    // tweaking deps here
    v1('ant:ant:1.6')
    v2('junit:junit:4.12')
}

task shadowJar1(type: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar ) {
  classifier = 'v1'
  configurations=[project.configurations.v1]
}
task shadowJar2(type: com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar ) {
  classifier = 'v2'
  configurations=[project.configurations.v2]
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, I got inspired by https://github.com/madmas/gradle-flavoured-artefacts/blob/master/application/build.gradle too. Still a bit disappointed that Gradle do not provide a clean way to achieve multi build like that :/